# Recursively glob for RSpec test files at runtime

Tags: ruby, rspec, rspec2

I have a suite of RSpec tests I want to group under the following hierarchy:

```
tests/
  featA/
     t1.rb
     t2.rb
  featB/
     t3.rb
```

but when I run

```
$ rspec tests
```

I get the following:

```
rspec tests
No examples were matched. Perhaps {:unless=>#<Proc:0x00007f318919cc08@/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-2.5.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:51>, :if=>#<Proc:0x00007f318919cdc0@/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-2.5.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:50>} is excluding everything?

Finished in 0.00003 seconds
0 examples, 0 failures
```

I feel like I'm going mad, but there doesn't seem to be a way to get RSpec to recursively glob for test files? Does this functionality exist?

EDIT:

I have a workaround by doing this:

```
$ rspec `find tests -name "*.rb"`
```

but I suspect I shouldn't have to. Am I right?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You've exposed an oversight on my part! In rspec-1, you could say this:

```
spec test --pattern "**/*.rb"
```

But the --pattern option is missing in rspec-2. I've just added it ([in development](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/commit/0c7a676e0274683795ebefdda2d5ee50ebdf1ccb)) and it will be included in the rspec-2.6.0 release.

Answer (score 1):

I usually manage running RSpec on my specs via [`rake`](http://rake.rubyforge.org/). The relevant portion of my `Rakefile` looks something like this:

```
require 'rspec/core/rake_task'

RSpec::Core::RakeTask.new(:spec) do |t|
  t.rspec_opts = ['--color', '-f progress', '-r ./spec/spec_helper.rb']
  t.pattern = 'spec/**/*_spec.rb'
  t.fail_on_error = false
end
```

Now `rake spec` runs RSpec with the appropriate options; you'll need to change `t.pattern` to match the specs you want to run.

Be sure to check out the [RSpec2 site](http://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-6-rc/dir/command-line/rake-task) for more information.

Comment: I'd go with this but perhaps you could also try something like rspec tests/**/**.rb ?

Comment: That particular invocation won't work, but maybe something similar. Also, I'm pretty sure that if you follow the RSpec convention and name your specs `whatever_spec.rb` that you could then just run `rspec tests`.

Comment: I did something like this a few days ago, I think the terminal session is still up on my MBP i'll look when I get home. I know it wasn't exact but close.